# Work done on a particle moving in a force field

Tags: vector-fields

Given a path C and a force field F, the work done on the particle can be found by

$$
\int_C \vec{F}\cdot \vec{r} \,dr
$$

This seems to suggest that you can find the work done *for any path*.

Doesnt the path depend on the force field? So given F, there is a limited range of paths. (Depending on starting position, velocity, mass)

Comment: no, not really.  for instance, gravity is  a force field, and when you walking around town, along whatever path, work is being done by gravity - less if you walk uphill, more if downhill.

Comment: I suppose the path depends on the force field if you assume that the force field is the _only_ force acting on the object.

Comment: The integral you've written down is incorrect, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral is answering you the question “If the particle would move along this path, how large *would* be the amount of work done by it regarding this force field?”, while the path it actually *will* take depends on every force field there is and the initial values.

The set of paths on which you can use the integral does not tell you anything about the paths that make physically sense.

Comment: So there can be several force fields. And you can find the work done by just one. I was thinking only of a net force field.

Comment: You can treat multiple force fields separately, but if you just consider one force field with no external forces, the path is (mostly) given by its initial conditions.